# Google Drive Permission API C# via Service Account throwing "abusiveContentRestriction" exception

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

All of a sudden started getting error.

`Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."] Location[ - ] Reason[abusiveContentRestriction] Domain[global]`

Uploading a file and then sharing the file permission through Service Account, the following Google Drive Permission API for sharing the file access to the email id.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

```
role: writer
type: user
emailAddress: someone@companydomain.com
```

This is happening for all the files, irrespective of the file content, so nothing wrong with the content. And same content works well with different service account which is in used for pre-production setup.

We've checked the available online resources, but that was not helping us.

**Update:** In our recent communication with the Google Team, they suggested impersonating the service account with actual user-account to avoid such kind of error which might be related to the service account limit hit.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the file itself and not related to the api

if your file was flagged you can go to the drive web application and request that the file be reviewed again [review](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2463328?hl=en)

if the file is uploaded to the server account drive account I don't think you can request a review.

It appears that the user may be a workspace domain user.   If the file was uploaded to the shard domain was domain wide delegation properly configured on the service account?  I also wonder what type of file this is.

Comment: This is happening for all the files, irrespective of the file content, so nothing wrong with the content. And same content works well with different service account which is in used for pre-production setup.

Answer (score 0):

Update: In our recent communication with the Google Team, they suggested impersonating the service account with actual user-account to avoid such kind of error which might be related to the service account limit hit. By impersonating it with domain wide authority, it worked.